# What is the character for romantic love in classical Chinese?

Tags: word-requests, classical-chinese

In Mandarin, 愛 means romantic love. However, [New Practical Primer of Literary Chinese](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/067402270X) by Paul Rouzer has this to say about its use in literary Chinese:

> This character [愛] usually does not imply "romantic love" in literary
>   Chinese, as it does in the modern East Asian languages.

So which character(s) are used for romantic love in classical Chinese?

Comment: I guess 戀 is quite close...and you can contrast this with erotic passions (艷). 愛 is a kind of benevolent love.

Answer (score 1):

This should be a clever question!

In classical Chinese
“爱” should be love to culture, nature, mess people or emperor(the culture emblem)
“恋” should be romantic love to another person, a butterfly loves a flower (蝶恋花)
“情” is a noun of “exist love/adore”, more clearly --“恋情”

For further,
“慕” should like “adore”, always use as “爱慕”, “倾慕”

---

In traditional/full Chinese writing these words are

> 愛、戀、蝶戀花、情、慕、愛慕、傾慕

Answer (score 0):

1, 愛, is traditional Chinese, be used it HongKong, Marcau, and Taiwan.
2, 愛，can be a noun, can be a verb. But 戀 is more focusing on verb. and they are not in same meaning. We say 我爱她。but never say 我戀她。
3, passions=激情， alluring=艷, 艷 more means on color.
4, In Chinese, every character is already very basic meaning, it must use in context, otherwise you hardly can use a basic character to present more meaning.
5, From a Chinese option, I never think / study Chinese in this style, hope you just read newspaper or book could improve your Chinese.

I am a developer, would like to find some technique thing, I don't know how / why I go into here, but whatever, hope I can explain well.

Comment: The question is about classical Chinese (古文, 文言, 漢文), and not about vernacular modern Mandarin (普通話, 華語, 白話文).

Comment: OK, I get you now. The previous statement also stands. You can not use just one character to stand for love(爱情) because, in traditional Chinese, this verb should be decorated. I provide you a website for your reference(if your Chinese is good enough): http://www.ruiwen.com/wenxue/shiju/296128.html @Flux